# stdatomic.h function on plain int - yields undefined or implementation defined behaviour?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, atomic, compare-and-swap

With GCC something like this compiles and probably works like expected:

```
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    (void)argc;

    int x   = 23;
    // XXX
    // instead of:
    // _Atomic int x = 23;

    int exp = atoi(argv[1]);
    int y   = atoi(argv[2]);

    printf("x = %d, exp = %d, y = %d\n", x, exp, y);

    bool b = atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&x, &exp, y);

    printf("x = %d, exp = %d, y = %d => %s\n", x, exp, y, b ? "true" : "false");
    return 0;
}
```

The [C reference says about such atomic functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_compare_exchange):

> This is a generic function defined for all [atomic object types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic) A. The argument is pointer to a volatile atomic type to accept addresses of both non-volatile and volatile (e.g. memory-mapped I/O) atomic variables. C is the non-atomic type corresponding to A.

This implies that the atomic functions like `atomic_compare_exchange_strong()` are not defined for non-atomic types.

Since `int` is a non-atomic type does the above code yields undefined behavior?

Or does the C standard specifies this as implementation defined behavior?

(where an implementation is able to define `int` as atomic type, as well - thus basically making it equivalent to `_Atomic int`)

Comment: I think this is UB because strict aliasing - accessing `int x` via `volatile _Atomic int *` pointer.

Comment: Added [tag:language-lawyer] as you probably want an authoritative std based answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not using _Atomic types for atomic functions is definitely undefined behaviour.  I am little surprised the compiler doesn't complain, but C is pretty forgiving.  Atomic functions provide a very specific guarantee about how they behave when multiple threads are modifying the same memory location at the same time.  Your simple example does not actually demonstrate this.

Read the description of [atomic types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic):

> Objects of atomic types are the only objects that are free from data races, that is, they may be modified by two threads concurrently or modified by one and read by another.

By not using atomic types you are no longer guaranteed to be able to access the values in an atomic way, thus making the atomic function useless.

Comment: The description of _Atomic type qualifier on cppreference, although very valuable, is some user-friendly interpretation of the standard. The exact rules are laid in [C11 7.17.7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.17.7). While I agree with that it should be `UB`, I don't agree with `it's definitely UB` and don't fully support the reason. I don't see how "that atomic types guarantee something" leads to UB when not using atomic types with `atomic_*` functions. Using non `_Atomic` types with `atomic_*` functions may not give that guarantee, but that doesn't mean it's undefined to use them.

Comment: @dohashi, how do you explain that atomic functions like `atomic_compare_exchange_strong()` don't feature the `_Atomic` type qualifier in their signatures? (they use `volatile` instead) @Kamil, exactly

Comment: It's explained in C11 7.17.1p5 and p6

Comment: While [C11 7.17.1p5](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.17.1p5) says that `_A_ refers to one of the atomic types`, so I would expect UB, the [note113](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note113) seems to use `atomic_compare_exchange_strong` with an non _Atomic type. In that note, if `T1` would be `_Atomic`, the `old op val` would be strange, as `old` has the type `T1`, so `old` would be `_Atomic` and is used on the right side of the expression (see 6.7.2.4p4). It looks like it was meant to be non`_Atomic`, at least for me.

Comment: @KamilCuk "Using non _Atomic types with atomic_* functions may not give that guarantee, but that doesn't mean it's undefined to use them." Without types that provide the required memory behaviour, the functions won't provide the correct behaviour.  Ultimately the spec does require atomic types, so passing something that is not atomic is out of spec.  To me that is going to be UB.